# Black screen after starting a game

Tags: drivers, nvidia, suspend, games, screen

When I launch a game, for example Football Manager 2022, which runs on Steam, I get a black screen, especially if my Pc was suspended or the screen was turned off before. After I restart the computer, the problem seems to resolves itself, but as soon as the computer goes asleep/suspend, the problem occurs afterwards again. I have noticed the same problem with Galactic Civilizations III (I have the native Linux game).
I am guessing it has to do with the Nvidia Drivers. I have a RTX 2070 Super.
Does anyone has/had the same problem, and did anyone found a solution?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you install your driver [this way](https://tutorialforlinux.com/2020/09/04/nvidia-rtx-2070-super-ubuntu-20-04-driver-installation/)? Or did you use some default drivers?

Comment: I didn't install it that way. I use the default drivers, actual proprietary driver, 470 version